# Weird behavior of CAST with 0 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Sorry for long query but its what im working with. 
I got this query in rails

```
@posts = Cama::PostType.first.posts.joins(:custom_field_values).where("(status = ?) AND (cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= ? AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= ? ) OR 
(cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = ? AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= ? AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= ? ) AND 
(LOWER(title) LIKE ? OR LOWER(content_filtered) LIKE ?)","published", "filtry-
powierzchnia", params['size-start'].to_i, params['size-end'].to_i,"filtry-
cena", params['price-start'].to_i, params['price-end'].to_i 
,"%#{params[:q]}%", 
"%#{params[:q]}%").group("cama_posts.id").having("COUNT(cama_custom_fields_rel
ationships.objectid) >= 2")
```

that make this sql

```
CamaleonCms::Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "cama_posts".* FROM "cama_posts"
 INNER JOIN "cama_custom_fields_relationships" ON 
"cama_custom_fields_relationships"."objectid" = "cama_posts"."id" AND 
"cama_custom_fields_relationships"."object_class" = $1 WHERE 
"cama_posts"."post_class" = $2 AND "cama_posts"."taxonomy_id" = $3 AND 
((status = 'published') AND 
(cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-powierzchnia'
AND CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 1 AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000 ) OR 
(cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-cena' AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 0 AND 
CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000000 ) AND
(LOWER(title) LIKE '%%' OR LOWER(content_filtered) LIKE '%%')) GROUP BY 
cama_posts.id HAVING (COUNT(cama_custom_fields_relationships.objectid) >= 2)
 ORDER BY "cama_posts"."post_order" ASC, "cama_posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT
 $4 OFFSET $5  [["object_class", "Post"], ["post_class", "Post"], 
["taxonomy_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 6], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

As you can see Im using CAST, I can't change column just to integer, because its CMS. I created custom_field that suppoust to be integer but table in db is still text so im forced to do it that way.

Now everything is ok if my

```
..CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 1..
```

but when this value will be 0 
so when my query will look like

```
CamaleonCms::Post Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "cama_posts".* FROM "cama_posts"
     INNER JOIN "cama_custom_fields_relationships" ON 
    "cama_custom_fields_relationships"."objectid" = "cama_posts"."id" AND 
    "cama_custom_fields_relationships"."object_class" = $1 WHERE 
    "cama_posts"."post_class" = $2 AND "cama_posts"."taxonomy_id" = $3 AND 
    ((status = 'published') AND 
    (cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-powierzchnia'
    AND ****CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 0**** AND 
    CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000 ) OR 
    (cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-cena' AND 
    CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 0 AND 
    CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000000 ) AND
    (LOWER(title) LIKE '%%' OR LOWER(content_filtered) LIKE '%%')) GROUP BY 
    cama_posts.id HAVING (COUNT(cama_custom_fields_relationships.objectid) >= 2)
     ORDER BY "cama_posts"."post_order" ASC, "cama_posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT
     $4 OFFSET $5  [["object_class", "Post"], ["post_class", "Post"], 
    ["taxonomy_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 6], ["OFFSET", 0]]
```

Im getting error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "/media/1/asd.jpg"
: SELECT  "cama_posts".* FROM "cama_posts" INNER JOIN "cama_custom_fields_relationships" ON "cama_custom_fields_relationships"."objectid" = "cama_posts"."id" AND "cama_custom_fields_relationships"."object_class" = $1 WHERE "cama_posts"."post_class" = $2 AND "cama_posts"."taxonomy_id" = $3 AND ((status = 'published') AND (cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-powierzchnia' AND CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 0 AND CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000 ) OR (cama_custom_fields_relationships.custom_field_slug = 'filtry-cena' AND CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) >= 0 AND CAST(cama_custom_fields_relationships.value AS INTEGER) <= 10000000 ) AND (LOWER(title) LIKE '%%' OR LOWER(content_filtered) LIKE '%%')) GROUP BY cama_posts.id HAVING (COUNT(cama_custom_fields_relationships.objectid) >= 2) ORDER BY "cama_posts"."post_order" ASC, "cama_posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $4 OFFSET $5):
```

and @posts return it on the query lvl so its not error that occurs somewhere else.

I tried CASTing to numeric, same problem.  It only happens when its starting condition, when there is another condition before it, it accepts 0 like in my example, the second condition after this one works with >= 0

Comment: `cama_custom_fields_relationships.value` seems to contain `/media/1/asd.jpg`, at least in some rows.

Comment: thats very weird if does really but it works from number 1... my guess is that it behaves maybe as NULL ? ITs really weird that it happens when 0

Comment: You need to look at the raw values in `cama_custom_fields_relationships.value`, something is putting `'/media/1/asd.jpg'` in it when you're expecting it to be a string containing an integer. Perhaps the rest of your query is getting the wrong `cama_custom_fields_relationships` rows in the zero case.

Comment: ok, it make sense. But this slug decide what kind of value should be there, thats why its weird for me. I will look at raw values, thank you